# Can I pass a type of enum as an argument in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a method that takes a parameter of type enum as a parameter and then operates on it to get all possible values of the enum type, and do some work with each of those values.

I'd be hoping for something like:

```
Widget foo (EnumType enumType) {
    for(var value in enumType.values) {
        print(value.name);
    }
}
```

I've looked for solutions but the only ones I can find are addressed by passing a list of the values as a parm, however this doesn't solve my problem as, even with the list of objects, I can't know that they are enum values so if I try do the `.name` operation on them, dart throws an error `Error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'Object'`.
Maybe my only problem is that I don't know how to specify a variable as an EnumType but I haven't been able to find a correct type for this.

Answer (score 4):

`EnumType.values` is the equivalent of an automatically generated `static` method on `EnumType` and as such is not part of any object's interface.  You therefore will not be able to directly call `.values` dynamically.

> I've looked for solutions but the only ones I can find are addressed by passing a list of the values as a [parameter], however this doesn't solve my problem as, even with the list of objects, I can't know that they are enum values so if I try do the `.name` operation on them, dart throws an error

You can use a generic function that restricts its type parameter to be an `Enum`:

```dart
enum Direction {
  north,
  east,
  south,
  west,
}

List<String> getNames<T extends Enum>(List<T> enumValues) =>
    [for (var e in enumValues) e.name];

void main() {
  print(getNames(Direction.values)); // Prints: [north, east, south, west]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with enums is that they can't be passed as a parameter, what you can do instead is that pass all the values and then extract the name from the `toString` method.

```
void printEnumValues<T>(List<T> values){
  for(var value in values){
    final name = value.toString().split('.')[1];
    print(name);
  }
}
```

Also I would recommend you look into freezed union classes as that might allow you an alternative approach towards the problem you're trying to solve.